# Remove special characters from object type columns of Data Frame and combine all string letter to form a sentences

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I have this column in my dataset. Tried to solve it by removing [ and { symbols from this as the whole column is a type string. Each character is a string including , : and spaces. while removing {. it only removes starting and ending not the in-between.

I want to extract only name values like 'Comedy', 'Thriller', ect.

Comment: The next time you post a question on StackOverflow, try to provide some code possibly with sample data in it, and an example of the expected result on the sample data. It's quite hard to extract the correct dataframe's structure and content from a screenshot where part of the data is cut away with three dots.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame([["[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]", np.NaN], ["[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]", np.NaN]], columns=['genres', 'homepage'])

df['genres'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.search(r"'name':\s*'(.*)'", x['genres'], re.DOTALL).group(1), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   genres  homepage
0  Comedy       NaN
1  Comedy       NaN
```

UPDATE:

If you have rows that contains more than a genre, you can extract all genres using this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json

def get_genres(string):
    string = string.replace("\'", "\"")
    j = json.loads(string)
    genres = [obj['name'] for obj in j]
    return ','.join(genres) # use `return genres[0]` if you want only the first genre found

df = pd.DataFrame([["[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}]", np.NaN], ["[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]", np.NaN]], columns=['genres', 'homepage'])
df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(get_genres)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
         genres  homepage
0  Comedy,Drama       NaN
1        Comedy       NaN
```

Comment: Getting an error stating "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Series".

Comment: I can not reproduce the error. If you copy and paste the above code it works. Check that your code is the same as mine. Probably, you have `df.apply(get_genres)` instead of `df['genres'].apply(get_genres)` - but I can not say this for sure without viewing your code.

To explain the error: it happens because the `get_genres` function (called by `apply`) receives pandas Series instead of strings. This means that `apply` is called incorrectly (but in my code is called correctly).

Answer (score 0):

```
def convt(str):
    return eval(str)


df['genre'] = df['genre'].apply(convt)
```

Comment: This works if you use `return eval(str)[0]['name']` (that is: interpret the content of the cell as a Python list of dictionaries and take the `name` property of the first dictionary in the list). But it has a security implication: if the dataframe you load has some Python code in a cell, it will get executed.